# How to clone an HTML element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a React component that clones an HTML element by its id.

I tried several ways but every time I get an error.

```
const [element,setElement] = useState()

useEffect(()=>{
    setElement(document.querySelector('#svg'))
},[])

return element
```

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLImageElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
const [element,setElement] = useState()

useEffect(()=>{
    let el = React.cloneElement(document.querySelector('#svg'))
    setElement(el)
},[])

return element
```

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Don't do this, this is completely against the React route.

Comment: @0stone0 why not do this?

Comment: `querySelector` should not be used in React. Check the React docs, or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198952/using-document-queryselector-in-react-should-i-use-refs-instead-how/59199347#59199347) about why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that `querySelector()` in **React** is an anti pattern. You should consider to use **refs** instead. Read more how to use **refs** in this thread: [Using document.querySelector in React? Should I use refs instead? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59199347/15113491)

To create a React component that clones an **HTML** element by its id with `querySelector()`, you can use `React.createElement` and pass it the **HTML** element, its tag name, and its properties as arguments.

**Example:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const CloneElement = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const htmlElement = document.querySelector('#svg');
    setElement(
      React.createElement(htmlElement.tagName, {
        ...htmlElement.attributes,
        children: htmlElement.innerHTML,
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return element;
};

export default CloneElement;
```

Comment: Don't do this, this is completely against the React route: `querySelector` should be avoided!

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted????

Comment: @0stone0  you might not like the use case but that doesnt make an answer incorrect.

Comment: Consider using cloneNode:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Comment: Yes it does. If you know React you should also know using querySelctor is a anti pattern.

Comment: @0stone0  I want to make a copy of an HTML element. I want to create a "Use" component. like in svg. It's comfortable

Comment: Not in every case it doesnt.  For example integrating with a third party thing that you might need to get a hold of a dom element for.

Comment: Thats also wrong, but yea, who cares. Good luck.

Comment: lol wrong.  aight

Comment: The OPs question is asking for enablement of a bad practice, I think it should be warned against without making it a bad question that should be downvoted. This answer enables a bad practice, it should include warnings about this being an anti-pattern and even advise against using it, but again does not necessarily make it a bad answer that should be downvoted. Warnings are useful to future readers and therefore have value on SO

Comment: @BrianThompson
 I want to ask. If the "Use" component becomes an exact copy of another component, is this a bad practice?

Comment: I'm not sure what a "Use" component is. It's also important to understand that an HTML element and a React element are very different things - so here you are not dealing with a "copy" of anything, but a component modeled after some element. I would say unless there is some very obscure edge case here that I'm missing, this would not be a good practice